# If $f^2$ is measurable, is $f$ also measurable? Prove, or give a counterexample.

Tags: measure-theory

I've proved the converse ($f$ is measurable, therefore $f^2$ is measurable), but I'm having trouble proving the above, or finding a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

There is a subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$ , which is not Borel measurable (Vitali !). Define $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by

$f(x)=1$ if $x \in B$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x \notin B$.

Then we have:

$\{x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \ge 1\}=B $ is not Borel measurable, but $f^2=1_{\mathbb R}$ is  Borel measurable